# Syntax error in inserting to excel sheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop

I was trying to insert data into the second sheet in an excel file, but it gives syntax error. I tried inserting with the same syntax in sheet1 and it was working fine. The sheet name is correct, column names are correct.
My code is

```
try
{
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
    System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand myCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
    string sql = null;
    MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='d:\\contacts_moorthy.xls';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
    MyConnection.Open();
    myCommand.Connection = MyConnection;
    sql = "insert into [Sheet2$] (To,Message,SentOn) values ('" + phonetxtbox.Text + "','" + messagetxtbox.Text + "','"+DateTime.Now+"')";
    myCommand.CommandText = sql;
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MyConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     MessageBox.Show("Error :",ex);
}
```

Comment: Can you share your connection setup as well?

Comment: Why are you not using the Excel automation interface in stead of the SQL approach? See for example http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302084

Comment: @kdmurray i have added the connection also..pls help

Comment: @ReinierTorenbeek i am a fresher. i was working with this codes. Sure  i will try the one u mentioned

Comment: I got the answer. If i don't specify the column names (To,Message,SentOn) it's working. i don'o why it is not working with the names,but the names are exact.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is is in your connection string for the Jet Provider.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

The connection string has n attribute called HDR. If you add "HDR=Yes;" to your connection string should indicates that the first row contains columnnames, which should solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

In my personal experience I noticed that it does not allow saving in Excel when the column names are not indicated in brackets "[]", that is to say it would be ... (`[To]`, `[Message]`, `[SentOn]` ).